# how can i start a song when app is in background mode

Tags: iphone

I want to stop all playbacks by playing a empty audio file when my app is in background I tried following code but I was not played.

```
 -(void)stop{
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
if(_viewController.checkIpod==0){
    AVAudioPlayer *playerA = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
               initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2sec" ofType:@"mp3"]]
               error:nil];


    [playerA play];
    //[player close];
    _viewController.onceClosed=1;
    NSLog(@"Oneclosed=1");
}
else{
    //[self.musicPlayer play];
    [_viewController.musicPlayer pause];
    [_viewController.playerA play]; 
    NSLog(@"closing and playing the sound");
}
```

}

I placed this code in beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler
Please help

Comment: As a user this would drive me crazy. I don't want an app in the background play any empty audio file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an item in your .plist to enable background audio. I think the property is 'Required background modes'.

Comment: see , when I am playing a audio an mean while app is going to background then it works but I have set a timer and want to play audio when timer finishes